# Create Color Variations From Main Color

Tags: flutter, colors

I have a main color in Flutter, `Color(0xFF6E8898)`, and what I want to do is create variations or shades from that color. For example here is a chart with different variations of one main color:

[image: Pie Chart With Variations]

Right now, I have one color, but I don't know how to create different shades or variations from it. Current Picture:

[image: Pie Chart With Single Color]

Thanks for any help.

---

**Note:** I don't think it matters, but just in case [`charts_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter#-readme-tab-) has a method for this I am using the `charts_flutter` library to generate my charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one can help you: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75417/how-to-make-a-given-color-a-bit-darker-or-lighter

You can write a function to generate color to lighter or darker with a given RGB color.

Answer (score 0):

The material colors have a shade attribute which you can use:

```
Colors.green.shade300
```

You can see a list of the shades of all the material colors [here](https://material.io/design/color/#tools-for-picking-colors).

Comment: But I'm not using a material color, I'm using the color: Color(0xFF6E8898)

Comment: Just create your custom color. That page provides a tool for that: https://material.io/design/color/#tools-for-picking-colors